# gaining access to aws instace or having the data that stored in postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, odoo, ssh-keys

I am trying to login to the aws instance using ssh and putty that having odoo v11 running, I followed different ways to get access but still, I cannot.

```
Errors in ssh :
permission denied (public key) ->  I was able to login with the same key suddenly I could not log in and no one changed the permission
```

also I changed the key pairs but still cannot log in

```
Errors in putty :
It shows (server refused our key) -> I get the same message with the previous key and the new one
```

Also, I made an EBS-Backed AMI and launched a new instance using a new key and I am still not gaining access

So my question is how to check the `.ssh` configuration?
And how to backup PostgreSQL database and add it to newly created odoo ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to reset the ssh-keys in an EC2 instance. You can find instructions how to do this from AWS documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#replacing-lost-key-pair.

Before doing this make sure you have an Odoo backup. You can use the Odoo web interface to create the backup so you do not need ssh access to server for that.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this ssh errors before and could be related to the change of the owner of the home user .ssh folder like /home/ubuntu/.ssh owner changed to another user like root or a deploy user.

Also you could make a backup at your Odoo instance URL, like:

http://example.com/web/database/manager

Just replace `http://example.com` with your own address